# tornado server with video streaming

Tags: python, web-server, opencv

I'm running tornado web server on my Raspberry Pi and its task is very simple. It just takes commands and sends them to an Arduino over serial.

I'm thinking of adding the Pi camera module and then doing a face detection program using opencv & python.

My main question here is, "Can tornado serve me well enough if I needed video streaming?" And if yes, "Can I can just import the libraries of both of tornado and opencv in single program?"

Answer (score 1):

This is almost impossible to answer as it depends on a lot of factors, but generally - yes, the pi and tornado will probably be able to have enough throughput for some of the resolutions.

You can definitely import many libraries into the same program.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

You can use opencv and tornado to solve your problem. There is a project [tornado stream mjpeg stream python](https://github.com/wildfios/Tornado-mjpeg-streamer-python) in github, but the project only fit the version less 5.11 of tornado. As for tornado 6, you should change the code a little. There is a [issue](https://github.com/wildfios/Tornado-mjpeg-streamer-python/issues/7) in this project to solve the problem. good luck.